# Why I can't scrape remote site data by php cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I used to scrape data from a remote website by php cURL. I even can scrape data now from all other pages except one page. The header from php cURL is showing this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2019 05:44:17 GMT Server: Apache Content-Length: 14 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 X-XSS-Protection: 1;mode=block X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains;preload X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
```

Anybody have an idea why this is happening and what will be the solution?

Comment: Can you post the URL at which you are hitting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert either, but when I did a simple Google search of all the sub-components of the returned header, this is what I found:

Part 1: `X-XSS-Protection: 1;mode=block` : This header is used to prevent Cross-Site scripting attack. The MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection) states:

> Enables XSS filtering. Rather than sanitizing the page, the browser will prevent rendering of the page if an attack is detected.

Part 2: `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` : This header prevents MIME based attacks. The MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options) states:

> This header was introduced by Microsoft in IE 8 as a way for webmasters to block content sniffing that was happening and could transform non-executable MIME types into executable MIME types. Since then, other browsers have introduced it, even if their MIME sniffing algorithms were less aggressive.

Part 3: `Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade` : The MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) states:

> The origin, path, and querystring of the URL are sent as a referrer when the protocol security level stays the same (HTTP→HTTP, HTTPS→HTTPS) or improves (HTTP→HTTPS), but isn't sent to less secure destinations (HTTPS→HTTP).

Part 4: `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains;preload` : This header prevents man-in-the-middle attack. The MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) states:

> The HTTP Strict Transport Security header informs the browser that it should never load a site using HTTP and should automatically convert all attempts to access the site using HTTP to HTTPS requests instead.

Part 5: `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin` : This header is used to prevent clickjacking attacks. The MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) states:

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>`. Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

So make sure you are not doing any of the above mistakes (like loading non-https version of the pages, or sniffing the MIME headers, etc.), and you should be good to load the content of the page.